# How to match a string which is in particular format?

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to check whether my string follows a particular pattern or not. My string will always start with `text_data_` and then followed by a number always as shown below

```
text_data_123
text_data_124
text_data_126
text_data_127
text_data_128
```

Now how can I check whether the string I am getting is in above format:

```
String value = getData();

// but this doesn't work?
if(value.matches("text_data(?<=_)\\d+")) {
    // found a match
}
```

What's wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lookbehind does not assert that what immediately precedes the current position is `_`.

You don't need to use lookbehind for this.

```
if(value.matches("text_data_\\d+")) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

using 'startsWith(String prefix)' method in String Class.

```
if (value.startsWith("text_data_")) {
    // found a match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

If(value.contains("text_data_")){
}

But I would suggest using dreaming cat's solution.